# Would you be allowed to get a government ID if you had no fingerprints?

Tags: civil-rights, americans-with-disabilities-act

Would you be allowed to get an ID sans prints if you did not have fingerprints because you'd lost your hands in an accident or something? What if a construction worker who had accidentally sanded his fingerprints off tried to get an ID?

Would it not be illegal to refuse a man an essential piece of documentation simply because he is disabled and has no hands?

Comment: Did I give fingerprints for my CA drivers license or U.S. passport? I don't think so.

Comment: I'm unaware of any US ID that requires fingerprints, but every fingerprinting requirement I've ever seen has explicitly exempted those who lack fingers.

Comment: @phoog I think CO gets fingerprints for driver's licenses, although I don't know if they are required.

Comment: Note that its also possible (but very rare) to lack the genes responsible for fingerprints. This report is from India, but still relevant:  https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-55301200

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Fingerprints are not required as part of the drivers-license application process.

Comment: Or a birth certificate

Comment: Or passport in the U.S.

Comment: Even if they were required, there would be a legal right to an accommodation under the ADA.